Debounce InlineCompletionProvider results in Monaco Editor
Using monaco-editor, I'm trying to implement Copilot-like features on top and providing OpenAI suggestions back to users. For that, I wrote and registered a custom monaco.languages.InlineCompletionsProvider
monaco.languages.registerInlineCompletionsProvider(
  'python',
  new MonacoCompletionProvider(),
)

MonacoCompletionProvider implements provideInlineCompletions which triggers calls to the OpenAI API. Unfortunately, by default, it gets called on every keystroke, resulting in numerous redundant network calls. And I could not find a way to change this behaviour.
Things I tried:

quickSuggestionsDelay setting. Doesn't seem to affect suggestions returned by an InlineCompletionsProvider.
Manual debouncing calls to provideInlineCompletions (i.e.: using debounce or throttle from lodash or similiar). This results in very janky behaviour with most returned suggestions not being rendered at all.

Is there a correct strategy to debounce/throttle calls to provideInlineCompletions?
